# Error in loading the gl extensions

Tags: opengl

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

```
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glewInit();

if (GL_TRUE != glewGetExtension((const char*) "GL_ARB_fragment_shader"))
  printf("GL_ARB_fragment_shader extension is not available!\n");

if (GL_TRUE != glewGetExtension((const char*) "GL_ARB_vertex_shader"))
  printf("GL_ARB_vertex_shader extension is not available!\n");

if (GL_TRUE != glewGetExtension((const char*) "GL_ARB_shader_objects"))
  printf("GL_ARB_shader_objects extension is not available!\n");


glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH); //set up the double buffering
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutCreateWindow("A basic OpenGL Window");

glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutIdleFunc(display);

glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

init();

glutMainLoop();

return 0;
```

and when i run the program, i get the following 
GL_ARB_fragment_shader extension is not available!
GL_ARB_vertex_shader extension is not available!
GL_ARB_shader_objects extension is not available!

Can anyone tell me why these extensions are not available ?
I have copied glew32.lib to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib
and glew32.dll  to the Debug folder of my Project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a valid GL context to query the extensions (which is created by `glutCreateWindow` in your code). Move the `glewInit()` and all other glew stuffer after you created (and made current, but GLUT does this for you) the context. You should also check for erros of `glewInit()` to spot such problems.

Comment: @user3055145: Mark the answer as accepted in that case, that is how this site is supposed to work ;)